# Issue using setEmptyView on a ListActivity

Tags: android

I have the following setup, and the empty view text doesn't show up...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setListAdapter(null);// to have empty list
}
```

The layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myScrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1">
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/emptyText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/contact_empty_help"
                android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.92" />
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

String is defined as:

```
<string name="contact_empty_help">"You don't have any contacts to display.\n\nTo add contacts, you have to:\n
        \n<li><font fgcolor="#ffffffff">Go to <b>Contacts</b></font> application to create new contacts\n</li>
        \n<li><font fgcolor="#ffffffff"><b>Import from VCF file</b></font>, this is available in Contacts menu, the file most be on the root of the SD card\n</li>"
        </string>
```

Since the list is empty, it should show me the text defined. I followed the example from the List8

https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List8.html
https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/list_8.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing a `setContentView(R.layout.listview);` and because of this the view was not picked upped by findViewById.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you doesn't need this line in your java code

`getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));`

The couple of Android ID `android:id="@android:id/list"` and `android:id="@android:id/empty"` are **exclusive** !

Best regards,
Division-par-zero.

Comment: I think this is only true in `ListActivity`s, I just removed this line from my code and the `emptyView` showed up on top of the populated list.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
```

be

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
```

? I don't know if that makes any difference.

Are you sure that `setListAdapter(null);` actually initializes the Adapter, rather than just ignoring the command?