# How To Test If Cursor Is Empty in a SQLiteDatabase Query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have an SQL table which is created by the following code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + _ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + SUBJECT
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + LECTURENUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PAGENUMBER
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + _DATA
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
}
```

I query the table as follows:

```
String sql = "SELECT " + _ID + "," + SUBJECT + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
    + " GROUP BY " + SUBJECT + ";";

Cursor cursor = subjects.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

The problem is I have to start an Activity A if the cursor is empty(i.e. the table is storing no values) and Activity B if the cursor is not empty(i.e. table is filled).

I am unable to find a method which can tell me if the table is empty or not.
I Have tried to used Log as follows:

```
private void showSubjectsOnList() {
    String sql = "SELECT " + _ID + "," + SUBJECT + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
        + " GROUP BY " + SUBJECT + ";";

    Cursor cursor = subjects.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

    Log.d("Events",Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
    if(cursor.isNull(0)!=false){
        cursor.close();
        subjects.close();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,OpenScreen.class));
    }
}
```

But the LOG shows 1, if the table is empty...and again 1, if table has 1 entry....it shows 2, if table has two entries and so on.

Can you suggest some method of solving my problem of starting different activities based on if cursor is empty or not.

Answer (score 63):

What about testing the cursor like this, and then doing what you've said:

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
```

> getCount ()

Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()

Comment: I have not tried exactly the way you mentioned. But I tried using 



        cursor!=null


as well, as follows:



       Log.d("Events",Boolean.toString(cursor!=null));



The interesting thing is Log shows true if the table has some values, but surprisingly the log is not shown at all if the table is empty. I am confused what does that mean.

Comment: Don't forget to move the pointer of the cursor to the first record with
`cursor.moveToFirst()` before you test

Comment: It means that your query returns zero-rows. Which means the cursor is not null but has zero rows :D

Comment: yes, i moved it to firstRow and used 

if(cirsor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)

It is not working =s.

Comment: @Nikoli, but the getCount is showing 1 in Log, even if the table is null and that is the thing pissing me off the most.

Comment: If the table is null then you'll get null pointer exception when you are trying to query the database object. Hmm...

Comment: No, because there is no point to get a NullPointerException,...otherwise whenever we create a Table for the first time, and use it in ListActivity, it should always show NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, thats why I said that table cannot be null.

Comment: ahan, now I got your point, But as I mentioned getCount() is 1 even if I have not entered any value in it...and It is not Null ofcourse.
Now how can I solce the actual problem.

Comment: An aggregate query without a "GROUP BY" clause, always gives exactly one row of data, even if rows = 0 of input data.

Comment: i am getting count zero and c==null; Cursor c= null;
        try {
            c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[]{date1});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i= c.getCount();
        if(c==null && c.getCount()==0)
            return true;
        else
            return  false;

        } but always return false;

Comment: @Nikola Despotoski I am doing cursor checking like below 

if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   cursor.close();  }

closing the cursor inside the loop will cost anything. And can the cursor in open state even it is null ?

Comment: NB: getCount() will fill cursor window to calculate number of rows. To make query more optimal, add "LIMIT 1" clause or use Cursor.moveToFirst() as suggested in another answer

Answer (score 25):

The easiest and cleanest way to test for an empty cursor is the following code:

```
if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
    // start activity a
} else {
    // start activity b
}
```

Per the docs, the method returns false if the cursor is empty:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29

> public abstract boolean moveToFirst ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Move the cursor to the first row.
>
> **This method will return false if the cursor is empty**.
>
> Returns whether the move succeeded.

Comment: What about cursor.moveToNext ()... I think this one will return true if there is rows and false if no row found...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use getCount().
If your sql is correct but doesn't return any row you will have a NOT null cursor object but without a rows and getCount() will return 0.

Comment: Cursor object is always returned when you query your DB. It has your query string inside, for instance. So it cant be null: in Java - identifier which is not "connected" to any object is null. Only if your select query didn't returned any rows - getCount() will return zero.

Comment: Hmm..ok...Thanks for elaboration. But How can I solve my problem then?

Comment: Check the query. I can see one bug now: query must not be closed with `;`.     http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29

Answer (score 2):

Deleted records remain in SQLite as null records, but `getCount()` counts only not null records. If your table has some records that are null, some of not null records will have `_Id` numbers bigger than result of `getCount()`. To reach them, you can iterate cursor ( using for() loop ) double the number of times than result of `getCount()` and use the cursor to fill record_Id numbers into an array. Lets say resulting array is `{ 1,  2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14 }`.

That means records 3, 4, 10, 13, are null records and your table has 14 record all together, not 10 that you got from `getCount()`.

Remember:

1. `getCount()` returns number of not null records ,
2. cursor returns `_Id` numbers of not null records,
3. `_Id` numbers "missed" by cursor are `_Id` numbers of null records,
4. must reach sufficiently further than `getCount()` to get them all.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be using a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

Those are Activity's which are meant to display items in a `ListView`. You can simply use a [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) to populate them (also illustrated in the `ListActivity`s JavaDoc page).

They also offer a [`setEmptyView()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29), which can be used to display a `View` (might be a `TextView`) which informs the user that there are no records yet and how he can create one.

An example on how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397203/problem-using-setemptyview-on-a-listactivity).

Comment: Dear Lukas,

The activity B is actually the listActivity. Even the method showSubjectsOnList() mentioned above is a method in this Activity. If the cursor in ShowSubjectsOnList in empty, I want to start Activity A, otherwise i want to remain in the same activity.....But i am unable to find how to find that cursor is empty.

Comment: Hey Lukas,
I got a hint. If setEmptyView() method can set a background on the listView, i do not have to start a new activity B, because the actual purpose of using Activity B is to avoid the bad look felt by empty List.....Let me try setEmptyView method and its usage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you're not creating a proper query.

You should use the SQLiteDatabase query.

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
```

You then can use c.getCount() to determine if the table has anything.