# Collect data from sqlite and display it in TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I was able to be extracted the data that interest me in this way:

```
Cursor stipcursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT (riepilogo) AS stip FROM "+DbHelper.RIEPILOGO+" WHERE MESI = 'Gennaio' and ANNI = "+anno+"", null);
                                            int colIndexstip = stipcursor.getColumnIndex("stip");
                                            if (colIndexstip == -1)
                                            return;
                                            else
                                            stipcursor.moveToFirst();
                                            double stip = stipcursor.getDouble(colIndexstip);
                                            System.out.println("Riepilogo"+stip);
```

the problem is that if the database has data, everything works, but if the database is empty, the application crashes.

Comment: This is not an answer, but an observation. Storing months as strings (month names?) instead of integers is **highly inefficient**.

Comment: But at the end everything in SQLite is a String, although not related to the answer.

Comment: Yes, in the database, insert data as strings, January, 2014.111111111 
I want to extract the numeric string 111111111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222873/android-finding-if-cursor-is-null-or-not.) post, try this

```
if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
    // start activity a
} else {
    // start activity b
}
```

cursor.moveToFirst() will return false if the cursor is empty. It works for me always.

You can try the first method given on that post also.