# Remove empty Dictionary Or list inside List in Flask

Tags: python

I have this code in python flask which could be easily return a result in json.

```
    for c2 in range(0, len(x1)):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid, tbl_users.tbluserid, CONCAT(tbl_users.firstname, tbl_users.lastname) AS mechandiser, tbl_single_role.userrole AS user_role FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_assigned_stores ON tbl_assigned_stores.tbluserid = tbl_users.tbluserid INNER JOIN tbl_single_role ON tbl_single_role.tblsingleroleid = tbl_users.tblsingleroleid WHERE tbl_users.tblsingleroleid = 2  AND tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid = '+tbl_hierarchy2[c2]+'' )
        da2 = [dict(((cur.description[i][0]), value)
                for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]

        print(da2)
return da2[0]
```

getting error in return, index is out of range that's because there are 2 empty list. here is the result in console

```
[{'tblstoreid': 439, 'tbluserid': 40, 'mechandiser': 'Charmain Miranday', 'user_role': 'Merchandiser (R)'}]
[]
[{'tblstoreid': 509, 'tbluserid': 79, 'mechandiser': 'Argie Alfelor', 'user_role': 'Merchandiser (R)'}]
[{'tblstoreid': 513, 'tbluserid': 72, 'mechandiser': 'Jomel Canopa', 'user_role': 'Merchandiser (R)'}]
[{'tblstoreid': 517, 'tbluserid': 72, 'mechandiser': 'Jomel Canopa', 'user_role': 'Merchandiser (R)'}]
[{'tblstoreid': 532, 'tbluserid': 70, 'mechandiser': 'Jessie Penaflorida', 'user_role': 'Merchandiser (R)'}]
[]
```

how can i remove those empty lists? i tried filter([], da2) and filter(None, da2) but no luck of it. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it creates a single list with a row for each result, which you can then return at the end:

```
da2 = []
for c2 in range(0, len(x1)):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid, tbl_users.tbluserid, CONCAT(tbl_users.firstname, tbl_users.lastname) AS mechandiser, tbl_single_role.userrole AS user_role FROM tbl_users INNER JOIN tbl_assigned_stores ON tbl_assigned_stores.tbluserid = tbl_users.tbluserid INNER JOIN tbl_single_role ON tbl_single_role.tblsingleroleid = tbl_users.tblsingleroleid WHERE tbl_users.tblsingleroleid = 2  AND tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid = '+tbl_hierarchy2[c2]+'' )
    da2.append([dict(((cur.description[i][0]), value)
            for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()])
```

When returning (outside the loop), you can either return the entire list including empty results using simply `return da2`, or you can return only non-empty rows with `return [row for row in da2 if row]`.

As an aside, using string concatenation to build queries is not recommended:

```
cur.execute('SELECT... AND tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid = '+tbl_hierarchy2[c2]+'')
```

Instead use a parameterised query to mitigate against [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/python) vulnerabilities:

```
cur.execute('SELECT... AND tbl_assigned_stores.tblstoreid = ?', (tbl_hierarchy2[c2],))
```

The syntax might be slightly different to the above depending on which database you are using, but the advice is applicable regardless.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, i applied it. but talking about "if row" im still getting a null list.

Comment: @itTech - I see why now. Before editing my answer I just want to check what the expected output from the return statement should be. Your return statement is outside the for loop, so will only ever return the last row (because `da2` is overwritten every time). Is that what you want? Or do you want it to return a list of all (non-empty) dictionaries?

Comment: yes that's what i want :) i think it should be detected before am going to return it as a result. but i dont know what statement should be fit on it. i tried many but none of them worked.

Comment: @itTech - I've edited the question, hopefully I've understood it correctly this time.

Comment: really appreciate your help sir and this is what exactly can solve my problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222873/how-to-test-if-cursor-is-empty-in-a-sqlitedatabase-query

im still going to test your solution. Thanks a lot :)