# ListView / ExpandableListView setEmptyView() has no effect

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to set empty view for three list views, namely 2 expandable and one list view, which are in different tabs:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null, false);
...
ExpListView1.setEmptyView(emptyView);
ListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
ExpListView2.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

It does no effect - empty view doesn't appear. Same with that code piece:

```
View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null, false);
View emptyRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) emptyView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view_layout);
ExpListView1.setEmptyView(emptyRelativeLayout);
```

empty_view_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/empty_view_layout">
    <TextView
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:id="@+id/empty_view_textview"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/no_items_in_list" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: UPD: When I tried to add empty TextView using specific @android:id/empty, it worked only for list view, but not for expandable views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding empty view as another content view to my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null);
    addContentView(emptyView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: I just understood how this whole thing works, thought I would share: both the list (`android.R.id.list`) and the empty view (`android.R.id.empty`) must be attached to the activity as contentView, this can also be achieved by putting them both in the layout xml file used by `setContentView`, so no inflation. Also there's no need to call `setEmptyView` if they have the aforementioned IDs: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2767974/253468. The advantage of having them in the same file is that you can customise where it shows up and how, easiest is to wrap both of them in a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Omitting `setEmptyView` is only possible in `ListActivity`s.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/expListView">

        </ExpandableListView>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmptyView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/no_game_available"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

TextView txtEmptyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmptyView);

expandableListView.setEmptyView(txtEmptyView);
```

Hope this will help you.