# Set empty view for expandable list wont work

Tags: android, layout, expandablelistview

So i am giving a filtering option to my expandable list, and when the filter come up with nothing i want to present an empty message that says "No Results" in the middle(both height and width) of the expandable list pre defined area, but I am having a very hard time.

When i add the empty view to the layout where the expandable list is, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
android:id="@+id/orderMenu">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchBarMenu"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Search for keyword(s), divided by comma"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/ResturantName"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<view
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    class="com.paze.CustomViews.MenuExpandableList"
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="8" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Finish Order"
    android:id="@+id/proceedButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

     <TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="No Items In your order"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I can see the text view always, but if i don't add it on the layout i just don't see anything:

```
           menuListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

where "empty" is a view on a special layout(not where the expandable list) i made for this.

plus how can i set the view in the middle of the empty expandable list?

Note:
When i filter, i set a new adapter, not updating the list of the current adapter.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your *special layout* to the activity's (the one containing the ListView) view hierarchy. Then just set the whole layout as list's empty view. Using layout lets you to place text wherever you want.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
final View inflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, null);
addContentView(inflated, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
listView.setEmptyView(inflated);
...
}
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454004/3172619