# setEmptyView() is not working for ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

When I used setEmptyView() method for listview, it worked. But when I used the same method for expandable listview, its not working. Is anyone else is facing a similar problem. Why its not working for Expandable Listview.

I just wrote these 2 lines:

```
mExpandListview.setEmptyView(emptyView);
mExpandListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Where `emptyView` is the id of the textview, which should be displayed if adapter is empty.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: setEmptyView(View) need a inflated view ref to add as paramater. Inflate first or create programtically and then add. You might b adding a ref a view which is already attached to another view.

Comment: actually the same technique worked when i used listview. So I thought itmworks in Expandable listview too..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView / ExpandableListView setEmptyView() has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400562/listview-expandablelistview-setemptyview-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please post some code and check this link

[ListView / ExpandableListView setEmptyView() has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400562/listview-expandablelistview-setemptyview-has-no-effect)

might be this can helpful to you.

Comment: Thank You for the reply. But in that link its given as: The problem was solved by adding empty view as another content view to my Activity. I want to know why we need to add another view. When its possible to set Empty View in listview, why its not possible in Expandable Listview. can you please tell me the reason behind this..?

Comment: @SangeethaPinto please read comment of TWiStErRob below above link answer

Comment: Neither duplicate things nor link-only answer is encouraged by SO.